# Fatal error: ` Class 'Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache' not found. Composer is not working properly

Tags: doctrine-orm, composer-php

I have started getting errors about missing classes (although they exist), though I have not changed anything. I have reinstalled the composer and vendor.

Sometimes I am getting the error:

> Class 'core\SomeClass' not found in <..>htdocs\type705c\src\bootstrap.php on line 310

Sometimes the error arose that the doctrine `ArrayCache` not found:

> Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache' not found in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.30-2\apache2\htdocs\type705c\src\bootstrap.php on line 258

I just keep deleting vendor/composer directory and sometimes get one or another error.

One class exists in
`\vendor\doctrine\cache\lib\Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache.php`

SomeClass class exists in  \core

Bootstrap.php

```
 <..> 

    use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
    use Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
    use Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache;


    $entitiesPaths = array( __DIR__.'/Bundle/Entity' );
    $proxiesPaths = array( __DIR__.'/Bundle/Proxies' );


    if ($isDevMode) {
        $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
    } else {
        $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache;
    }

    $config = new Configuration;
    $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
    $driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver($entitiesPaths);
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
    $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);
    $config->setProxyDir($proxiesPaths);
    $config->setProxyNamespace('DoctrineProxies\__CG__\Bundle\Proxies');

    if ($isDevMode) {
        $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);
    } else {
        $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(false);
    }
    <..>

$some='some';
echo "<br> 307 ".$some; //echoes if ArrayCache is found, else do not 

use core\SomeClass;
$ecind = new SomeClass();
```

At this point, if there are no errors with ArrayCache, arose error that core\SomeClass.php  is missing, and I do not see it in autoload_static.php, thus it is really missing.

I always use the same composer dump-autoload to generate namespaces.

autoload_static.php  ( in case the  `ArrayCache` not found. )

```
    // autoload_static.php @generated by Composer

    namespace Composer\Autoload;

    class ComposerStaticInita89eb0d2fe0809574fc31efca00ceb2f
    {
        public static $prefixLengthsPsr4 = array (
            'c' => 
            array (
                'core\\' => 5,
            ),
            'R' => 
            array (
                'RedeyeVentures\\GeoPattern\\SVGElements\\' => 38,
                'RedeyeVentures\\GeoPattern\\' => 26,
            ),
            'L' => 
            array (
                'Bundle\\Resources\\Fnc\\' => 24,
                'Bundle\\Entity\\' => 17,
            ),
            'D' => 
            array (
                'DoctrineProxies\\__CG__\\Bundle\\Entity\\' => 40,
            ),
        );

        public static $prefixDirsPsr4 = array (
            'core\\' => 
            array (
                0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/core',
            ),
            'RedeyeVentures\\GeoPattern\\SVGElements\\' => 
            array (
                0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/ComponentsOthers/geopattern-php-master/src/GeoPattern/SVGElements',
            ),
            'RedeyeVentures\\GeoPattern\\' => 
            array (
                0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/ComponentsOthers/geopattern-php-master/src/GeoPattern',
            ),
            'Bundle\\Resources\\Fnc\\' => 
            array (
                0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/Bundle/Resources/Fnc',
            ),
            'Bundle\\Entity\\' => 
            array (
                0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/Bundle/Entity',
            ),
            'Bundle\\DataFixtures\\ownFixtures\\' => 
            array (
                0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/Bundle/DataFixtures/ownFixtures',
            ),
            'Bundle\\DataFixtures\\ORM\\' => 
            array (
                0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/Bundle/DataFixtures/ORM',
            ),
            'Bundle\\Controller\\' => 
            array (
                0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/Bundle/Controller',
            ),
            'Bundle\\Components\\StringC\\' => 
            array (
                0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/Bundle/Components/StringC',
            ),
            'Bundle\\Components\\SocialC\\' => 
            array (
                0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/Bundle/Components/SocialC',
            ),
            'Bundle\\Components\\HttC\\' => 
            array (
                0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/Bundle/Components/HttC',
            ),
            'Bundle\\Components\\FormC\\' => 
            array (
                0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/Bundle/Components/FormC',
            ),
            'Bundle\\Components\\FileC\\' => 
            array (
                0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/Bundle/Components/FileC',
            ),
            'Bundle\\Components\\ErrC\\' => 
            array (
                0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/Bundle/Components/ErrC',
            ),
            'Bundle\\Components\\ArrayC\\' => 
            array (
                0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/Bundle/Components/ArrayC',
            ),
            'DoctrineProxies\\__CG__\\Bundle\\Entity\\' => 
            array (
                0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/Bundle/Proxies',
            ),
        );

        public static $prefixesPsr0 = array (
            'M' => 
            array (
                'Migrations' => 
                array (
                    0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/migrations',
                ),
            ),
            'L' => 
            array (
                'Bundle\\Entity\\' => 
                array (
                    0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/Bundle/Entity',
                ),
            ),
        );

        public static $fallbackDirsPsr0 = array (
            0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src',
        );

        public static function getInitializer(ClassLoader $loader)
        {
            return \Closure::bind(function () use ($loader) {
                $loader->prefixLengthsPsr4 = ComposerStaticInita89eb0d2fe0809574fc31efca00ceb2f::$prefixLengthsPsr4;
                $loader->prefixDirsPsr4 = ComposerStaticInita89eb0d2fe0809574fc31efca00ceb2f::$prefixDirsPsr4;
                $loader->prefixesPsr0 = ComposerStaticInita89eb0d2fe0809574fc31efca00ceb2f::$prefixesPsr0;
                $loader->fallbackDirsPsr0 = ComposerStaticInita89eb0d2fe0809574fc31efca00ceb2f::$fallbackDirsPsr0;

            }, null, ClassLoader::class);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason was,

that by accident i have moved core folder to another location, thus composer.json does not point to the right folders and classes are not found.

instead of `/src/core`
i moved by accident from `/src` to `/core`